# Count returned by a Query when Particular column is null and not-null in MySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate

i want to `select a count returned by a query when a particular column is null` and another `query to select a count when that column is not null` into single query how can i achieve it..?

i had tried some of the example that are avail in SOF but no use..

for example i want to

```
select students count of class table where the address null and notnull
```

Comment: hi, could you create your schema here so we can help you out: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
 SUM( CASE when studentId is not NULL THEN 1 else 0 END ) as result1 ,
 SUM( CASE when studentId is NULL THEN 1 else 0 END) as result2
from class
```

Comment: IF is alternate of CASE as i have used in my answer

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL this can do it

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(address IS NULL,1,0))       as  `Student_With_No_Address`,
    SUM(IF(address IS NOT NULL,1,0)) as    `Student_With_Address`
FROM students
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo

Output :

```
Student_With_No_Address |   Student_With_Address
---------------------------------------------
        4               |           6
```

Comment: @sakar i dont understand what you mean. i provided an example according to your question. If you need something else always post 4 thisngs. Schema , sample Data , Desiredoutput and what you have tried so that is is ease for people to understand and answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE when address is null then 1 end) AS StudentsWithNoAddress,
COUNT(CASE when address is not null then 1 end) AS StudentsWithAddress 
FROM Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write two `SELECT` statements and combine them using `UNION`

```
SELECT 'No Address' AS AddressStatus, COUNT(*) AS NoOfStudents 
FROM Class WHERE Address IS NULL
UNION
SELECT 'With Address' AS AddressStatus, COUNT(*) AS NoOfStudents 
FROM Class WHERE Address IS NOT NULL
```